How can I keep standalone lockfiles working in a mono-repo managed by Yarn?
I'm using a monorepo with Yarn workspaces as a means to manage a dozen or so WordPress plugins. Each plugin needs to be able to build (webpack) and deploy independently.
The issue happens occasionally while adding packages or using yarn upgrade-interactive. The yarn.lock files of the children end up not reflecting all of the dependencies that they require. The packages will build correctly locally, but will fail to build on the remote server because of missing packages (that are presumably present locally because of one of their siblings or parent).
This can be resolved by removing the contents of yarn.lock and running yarn install in the child. However, I would like to figure out the root cause and prevent it.
My .yarnrc.yml files are all:
compressionLevel: mixed

enableGlobalCache: false

nodeLinker: node-modules

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-4.3.1.cjs

and my root package.json has its workspaces defined as:
{
    "workspaces": [
        "themes/*",
        "plugins/*"
    ]
}


When using yarn workspaces, there is no need to run yarn install in the individual workspaces/projects. You don't need those yarn.lock files in the packages. You only need to run yarn install in the root of the repository. This will install dependencies for all the workspaces, and the resulting yarn.lock file at the root will contain resolutions for all the packages needed by all workspaces.
If you have any yarn.lock files at themes/* or plugins/* you can safely delete them.

I realize that is the case when the workspace represents the whole project. However, in this case, each of the sub-directories within themes/* and plugins/* are their own repositories that can be built and deployed independently without the parent workspace necessarily being present.

In that case, you can't use workspaces.. They are meant for mono repos where projects share build infrastructure... they are meant to be built together.
